# Console not showing ( just the form ) on running a Console app( .net CORE ) with winform dll

Tags: winforms, .net-core, dll, visual-studio-2019

EDIT :

i added the folliwing in my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

it works now !

BUT only the form is showing up ? Any work-around for the console to show up along with Form ?

---

---

My previous question on the topic was unclear . Hence , I am trying to reframe it .

I basically have a library written as Console app (.net Core) , which I want to release.
Before releasing, I want to create a form so that any user who uses the library sees the form ( asking for his contest to send user data).

/******************  ISSUE ******************************/

Now , to create the form I added assemblies for System.Windows.Forms and wrote the basic code in main :

[image]

But on running it , no preview for the form is shown ... just the console window

If I do the same on a Console app for .NET FRAMEWORK -> adding the dlls for form and design and then writing same code in main , I get a preview of Form .

Then why is it not showing in case of .NET CORE console app ?

also , the program.cs file in the picture does appears to get changed to a form version by the icon . but clicking it  gives me the error :

[image]

So how to add a pop up or form in .NET CORE console app ?

Comment: do you want to show the form and console window at the same time in a .net core console app?

Comment: Yes , i wanted that but wasn't able to show the console together with form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps to show the console together with form.

First, please add a project called Widows Forms Class Library in your visual studio 2019.
(Please choose .net core 3.0)

[image]

Second, please add a form to the library.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello, world");
        }
    }
```

Third, we can add the library to the .net core 3.0 console app.

Finally, we could use the following code to show the form and console in the console app.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello,world");

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new TestForm());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Result:

[image]